# Can't get guest session working with verification

Tags: php, html, sql, session

I want to make a page that verifies the id and surname with a database and then makes two sessions for both the id and surname.

This is the code I have at the moment

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="number" placeholder="ID" name="id" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Achternaam" name="naam" required>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Inloggen" id="login"><br>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && isset($_POST["naam"]) ){
    $x = $_POST["id"];
    $y = $_POST["naam"];

    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","zwartebergen");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $a=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id,achternaam FROM gast WHERE id=\"$x\"");
        $query = "SELECT id,achternaam FROM gast WHERE id=\"$x\" AND achternaam=\"$y\"";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($a)){ 
                $g=$row['0'];
                $t=$row['3'];

            if($g==$x && $t==$y){
                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                $_SESSION["naam"] = $naam;
            }else{
                echo "<font class='offset' color='red'>Fout ID of Achternaam!</font>";
                }
            }
        }
        else{
        echo "<font class='offset' color='red'>Deze gebruiker is niet geregistreerd!</font>";
    }
}
?>
```

I want the input types to match the rows 0 and 3 in the database as mentioned in the code above.
For example the database has the ID 1000 and has the surname "Surname"

Then if I input in the input types 1000 and Surname it has to put these two values in two sessions and then echo them

Comment: did you started session ? by `session_start()`

Comment: You need to call `session_start()` before set values in session variable.

Comment: have to start the session top of your page session_start()

Answer (score 0):

To store session data, you must first call the `session_start` function first. You can then store the values you wish and use them elsewhere.

Like this:

```
session_start(); // begin the session

if($g==$x && $t==$y){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['naam'] = $naam;
}
```

You can then use them later, for example:

```
echo $_SESSION['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to start the `session_start();` at top of the page page.

And also you have to start every page wherever you use the session variable.